# File write failed in android with java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, file

I am trying to perform file write operation in android 4.4.4 version running in Moto G.
I added file write permission in manifest file too. But file write is keep on failing in all possible ways.

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This is the error message i am getting. and my code is below,

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/text.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
              try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write("hi");
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I tried in all possible ways. But could't find solution.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />in mainfest

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` ""outside"" your application tags

Comment: I added the following permission in manifest.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

But no luck...

Comment: test on emulator then check the size of sd card, increase if it is less

Comment: I tried in emulator as well. Same error message shown.

Comment: have you increase the size of sdcard ?

Comment: Yes i tried increase the size from 64MB to 256MB.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //check if external storage is available and not read only 
  if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) { 

  }
  else {
   myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
  }

 private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() { 
  String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) { 
   return true; 
  } 
  return false; 
 } 

 private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() { 
  String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) { 
   return true; 
  } 
  return false; 
 }
```

and try this
link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

```
context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into
```

Using the Internal Storage

link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

link:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-internal-external-storage.html

Comment: moto g dont have external storage so try to write in internal storage and please post your mainfest

Comment: Hi All, I fixed the issue. I forgot to add write permission in application_to_test manifest. Once added, issue is gone. Thanks for all your tips.